# What is the use case for Kotlin contracts in Android development

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been investigating Google's Architecture samples.

https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/master

And what I noticed is a lot of use of `contracts`

For example: in `TasksActivity` we find this code:

```
private fun setupNavigationDrawer() {
    drawerLayout = (findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout))
        .apply {
            setStatusBarBackground(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
        }
}
```

and before `contracts` we would write it like this:

```
private fun setupNavigationDrawer() {
    drawerLayout = (findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout))
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
}
```

When clicking `apply` we see `InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE` which appears that this contract makes sure that the `setStatusBarBackground` method is only called once.

What is the practical benefit of this checking and when should it be used? Because it is more code and less readable in my opinion.

Comment: Contracts are basically hints for the compiler. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts

Answer (score 2):

Contracts were added in Kotlin 1.3, but `apply` has been around forever. The contracts are only compiler hints, and allow functions like `apply` to have additional use cases (like the ability to initialize a `val`).

`apply` is more commonly used for code conciseness. Your example is an edge case where it's debatable whether the code is cleaner with it. If you're calling a series of set-up functions on an object, it's more obviously helpful for clarity and conciseness.

Comment: The whole idea of architecture samples is to showcase best practices. But when adding contracts where they don't have a clear use case makes things only unnecessary complex because in this example you don't initialize a val. If I understand you correctly, in the same project in the DefaultTasksRepositoryTest.kt there is a line: val completedTask = task1.copy().apply { isCompleted = true }. This would be a valid use case, to initialize a var on a object?

Comment: They aren't using `apply` here because `apply` has a contract. For all I know, this code in the library predates Kotlin 1.3. They are most likely using `apply` here because it is a Kotlin convention to initialize an object and then immediately configure it with `apply`. Personally, I think it's questionable to use it if the configuration is only one line, but that's a style choice.

Comment: The primary purpose of `apply` is configuring an object without repeating the name of its variable. It also lets you create and configure an object to pass to a nullable property without doing null checks. The contract that was added later lets you do additional stuff with `apply` that is probably uncommon.